# Calculate the integrals for $f(x) = x^2 + 1$

Tags: calculus, integration

Let $ f \colon \ \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ so that $ f(x) = x^2 + 1$. Then compute $$15\int_0^1 f^7(x) \,dx - 14\int_0^1 f^6(x) \,dx$$

There is the direct calculation option for me: using Newton binomial, exploiting $(x^2+1)^7$ and $(x^2+1)^6$ and then integral all terms.

Is there any other elegent solution?

Comment: Do you know integration by parts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By integration by parts we have \begin{align*} I  & = \int_{0}^{1} (x^2 + 1)^7\ dx \\ & = x(x^2 + 1)^7 \ \bigg |_{0}^{1} - 14 \int_{0}^{1} \left [(x^2 + 1)^7 - (x^2 + 1)^6 \right ]\ dx \end{align*}

Can you now finish?

So the required integral evaluates to $2^7.$

Comment: Can you show me how you get this: [(x2+1)7−(x2+1)6] ?

Comment: In the second integrand you would get $14 (x^2 + 1)^6 x^2$ which can be rewritten as $14 [(x^2+1)^7 - (x^2 +1)^6].$

Comment: I think it's $14(x^2+1)^6x^2$. I'm curious how you get that difference

Comment: Because second integral of the integration by parts here is $$\int_{0}^{1} \frac {d} {dx} [(x^2+1)^7] \int dx.$$

Comment: Elegant indeed. Great answer.

Comment: Yeah you are right @Akhtubir. Got a typo. Now I have rectified it. Please check once again.

Comment: Thanks @Kaster.

Answer (score 1):

Put

$$I_n=\int_0^1(x^2+1)^ndx$$

Integrating by parts:

$$u=(x^2+1)^n,\ dv=dx,\ du=n(x^2+1)^{n-1}2xdx, v=x$$

$$I_n=uv|_0^1-\int_0^1vdu=x(x^2+1)^n|_0^1-2n\int_0^1x^2(x^2+1)^{n-1}dx$$

$$I_n=2^n-2n\int_0^1(x^2+1)(x^2+1)^{n-1}dx+2n\int_0^1(x^2+1)^{n-1}dx$$

$$I_n=2^n-2nI_n+2nI_{n-1}$$

$$(1+2n)I_n-2nI_{n-1}=2^n$$

For $n=7$:

$$15I_7-14I_6=2^7=128$$